# Import cell value from google sheets to website?

Tags: web, google-sheets, cell

I wonder if it is possible to import a cell value from google sheets to a website? 
Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a few ways to do this.  I would send an HTTP Request to a Stand Alone Apps Script Content Service script that returned the value of the cell.  Write a program in Apps Script:

[Apps Script Link](https://script.google.com)

### Create a `doGet()` function:

```
function doGet() {
  //This Apps Script is Used to get a cell value out of a spreadsheet

  var theSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getFileById('Your File ID');
  var theSheet = theSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet name');
  var theCell = theSheet.getRange("A1");
  var theContent = theRange.getValue();
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(theContent);
};
```

I don't know whether you plan on using server side code, or a JavaScript AJAX request, or what you website uses for server side code.

Comment: But do you know how I connect the function to html. Where I find the code I should have in the html sheet?